# Cannot input unicode characters in PHP 8 interactive shell

Tags: php

After upgrading to PHP 8, I can no longer input any characters outside the standard ASCII in PHP interactive shell (the `php -a` command). In my native language there are many umlauts, but nothing happens when pressing such a key on my keyboard.

If I revert to older PHP, PHP 7.4 for example, there is no such problem in the same terminal window.

Any suggestions or ideas, what to try to overcome this problem?

Comment: Since this sounds more like a configuration problem, I suggest that you ask this at [su].

Comment: seems to be a bug in PHP 8, I already reported this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81598